# Scala: getting error while creating sbt project: sbt import cancelled

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

[image]

I'm getting this error when creating a sbt project. I do have an Ubuntu-18.04 but don't know why it is picking that here.

Comment: I opened a YouTrack issue about this last year (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-18837) - honestly I haven't kept up with progress on this ticket as I don't develop on Windows very often but that might give you a starting point.

Comment: It's still open.

Comment: Got the solution:

1. Open project-> File -> Project Structure -> "Platform Settings"-> Select your JDK path (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221) ->Apply and Finish                                                              
  2. Now, select the "SDK" option from the left panel list-> Update the same path -> Apply and Finish
3. From the main project screen-> click 'sbt' from the top-right side-> click the refresh icon
4. It will start building the project again with the required dependencies